# UIView height is not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a `UIView` called updatesView which is a subview of the main view. Based on some conditions, the view height changes. But view height changes only once. Next time when I change it, it displays the previous height itself.

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
         if (userLoggedIn)
            [self resetSubviews];
         else
            [self setupSubviews];
    }

    -(void)resetSubviews
    {
        CGRect updateFrame = self.updatesView.frame;
        updateFrame.size.height =self.notificationContainerView.frame.size.height - self.headerView.frame.size.height;
        self.updatesView.frame = updateFrame;
    }

    - (void)setupSubviews
    {
        CGRect updateFrame = self.updatesView.frame;
        updateFrame.size.height = self.notificationContainerView.frame.size.height - self.tabView.frame.size.height - self.buttonsView.frame.size.height - kHomeTabbarHeight - 5;
        self.updatesView.frame = updateFrame;
    }
```

Suppose initially while running the app the userIsLoggedIn, then it executes the first condition. Now if I logout (in another `UIViewController`) and come back, the else condition is executed,but while displaying the height does not change.

Similarly, initially while running app if the else condition is executed, then the entire time the view height remains the same as set in that condition.

I am not using autolayout. But I have used autoresizing. Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How can you not use autolayout when you used constraints in storyboard? o_O 
Constraints supported only in autolayout!

Comment: I meant autoresizing.

Comment: you cannot change height width directly. You have to change frame of view with updated height

Comment: I am interested how you are going to change height without changing frame. This code should not compile

Comment: I have edited the code. I was using height directly because I was using a third party library which was internally setting height based on the frame.size.height.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to help you - what have you already tried to solve this problem? What does the debugger show for the `userLoggedIn` value when returning after logging out? Does the debugger show `resetSubviews` being called correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Please use autolayout. Define a height constraint for the view, make a property for this constraint and change the value.

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = XXXX;
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing self.updatesView.frame.height.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view with view's  `setNeedsLayout` 
   and `layoutIfNeeded` methods combined.

Call these method's when you update view's height.